# Does it make sense to set Http Cache Headers on a 404 response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, iis-7

I have a database that stores images which can be access via a primary key ID (vomit, I know, but it's out of my control).

I have a pretty standard Asp .net Mvc Controller that reads the database and if a row is found in the database it returns the image bytes as a FileResult. If a row is not found, I have a custom action result that sets the response status to 404. I do not throw an exception, but instead let IIS handle the 404 status and return a static file.

```
public class ContentMediaNotFoundResult : ActionResult
{
    public ContentMediaNotFoundResult() { }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        //-- Here the only thing we are doing is setting the Response code to 404 and then we are   going to let IIS service the request
        //-- based on the settings in system.webServer/httpErrors (which may come from the root .config, so be careful)
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

Recently, we were testing on Firefox v3.6.1 and were noticing the browser was making multiple requests (3 to be precise) for each image, hence our controller factory was being hit 3 times and going to the database 3 times from our action method. This behavior was only happneing from Firefox (IE, chrome were normal).

My question is, does it make sense to add Http Cache Headers to 404 responses in my ContentMediaNotFoundResult so that my action method doesn't hit the database continually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can set Cache headers for 404s. As @Darin mentioned, your cache aging may affect any issues with replacing a 404'd image, but that's the same problem with caching any object that may change.

Seems like only 5xx errors should probably not be cached, but 4xx are fine.

Comment: I agree 500 and 501 probably shouldn't be cached but I think 503 might be good one to put short caching headers on.  It might help stop people hammering your server while you get it back on line.

Comment: Firefox doesn't cache 404 nor 400 responses. It will not respect http cache headers. This is apparently by design. You can use 410 which is cacheable and will use Cache-control header. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

Comment: @Nux reading your commen I fear you're right about FF. Still could not find any sources that confirm FF's 404/400 design choice not to cache those. Can you maybe provide more info about this?

Comment: RFC 7231 stipulates that 404 responses are cahceable: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.404 If Firefox is never caching 404s, they're deviating from the spec.

Answer (score 3):

My view is that it depends. If you have a fast-changing Web API where a resource might be added any moment, then you'd want clients to always query the origin.

If you have a lot of content that doesn't change much, caching 404 might help alot.

Check this real-world example out:

http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/26/strategy-caching-404s-saved-the-onion-66-on-server-time.html

Comment: I also tried to use browser cache for 404 errors and I have found few weird scenarios. When I type in the URL "testsite.com/testblabla.png" we are getting an 404 response with e-tag and if I refresh the same browser tab it is not using the browser cache where as If I open the same url in a new tab it is using it from browser cache. So weird, also on firefox is not using the browser cache for 404 status at all. Guys, please let me know if you also face the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to set cache headers on 404 pages because if later an image with this id added to the database the user would still be getting 404s. Maybe you should try to understand why does FireFox sends 3 requests to this url.